# Use HTTP/HTTPS Target Depending On Request

Tags: apigee

We're trying to modify an existing apigee API proxy to use the HTTPS target endpoint if the incoming request is HTTPS and use HTTP if the request is also HTTP.  I presume I can use `virtualhost.ssl.enabled` and create a `RouteRule` based on that?  Or is there a preferred (or easier?) way of doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring to [Apigee variables](http://apigee.com/docs/api-services/api/variables-reference#-a-class-jumplink-name-request-a-request-message-variables), the variable `client.scheme` contains http or https depending upon the client's request. `virtualhost.ssl.enabled` may also work as well, but `client.scheme` seems more straightforward to me. You should be able to use these RouteRules:

```
<RouteRule name="httpTarget">
  <Condition>client.scheme == "http"</Condition>
  <TargetEndpoint>httpTarget</TargetEndpoint>
</RouteRule>
<RouteRule name="httpsTarget">
  <!-- default to https -->
  <TargetEndpoint>httpsTarget</TargetEndpoint>
</RouteRule>
```

Note that the last RouteRule has no condition -- it is generally best practice to have at least one RouteRule (the last one evaluated) always match.